# How to get Kafka timestamp for a record in Flink?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I have a `Flink` application that uses the `FlinkKafkaConsumer`.

I am interested in retrieving the `Kafka` timestamp for a given `record/offset` using the `KeyedDeserializationSchema`. It seems that the topic, partition, offset, and message are available.

How can the timestamp be obtained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `ConsumerRecord.timestamp()` - the timestamp in milliseconds since beginning of the epoch (midnight Jan 1, 1970 (UTC)).
The timestamp type is indicated in timestampType().

Comment: How do you know it? Documentation says nothing.